# Disable button if no checkbox is checked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jquery function for multiple delete.

```
  $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('[id^=partners_], [id^=invitations_], [id^=clients_], [id^=partner_services_], [id^=partner_products_]').on("click", function (event) {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  })
```

The problem is, if I have 2 items, select both and then deselect one of them, the 'delete' button disables again.

How can I disable the button only if no checkbox is checked?
Do I have to implement an each function?

Comment: I'd prefer `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', ($('[id^=partners_]:checked, [id^=invitations_]:checked, [id^=clients_]:checked, [id^=partner_services_]:checked, [id^=partner_products_]:checked').length == 0));
```

This will `disable` the button depending on the second parameter evaluation state.

If it is `true`, button will be disabled, if not button will be enabled.

`$('[id^=partners_]:checked, [id^=invitations_]:checked, [id^=clients_]:checked, [id^=partner_services_]:checked, [id^=partner_products_]:checked').length` will get the number of checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : get all checkbox selector in one variable and bind the click event to it. Inside click handler see if any of the checkbox is checked then enable / disable the button accordingly. Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
var $checkbox = $('[id^=partners_], [id^=invitations_], [id^=clients_], [id^=partner_services_], [id^=partner_products_]');
  $($checkbox).on("click", function (event) {
      $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', $checkbox.is(':checked').length==0);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable `flag` to count how much checkbox is checked, if atleast one is checked then remove disabling else you know.

```
  $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('[id^=partners_], [id^=invitations_], [id^=clients_], [id^=partner_services_], [id^=partner_products_]').on("click", function (event) {
    var flag = 0;  //HERE IS THE VARIABLE
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        flag += 1;  //HERE
    } else {
        flag -= 1;  //HERE
    }
  });

if(flag <= 0)
{
    $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
else {
    $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('[id^=partners_], [id^=invitations_], [id^=clients_], [id^=partner_services_], [id^=partner_products_]').on("click", function (event) {
    if ($(this).siblings().andSelf().prop("checked").length > 0) {
        $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('input.delete-selected[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
})
```

Comment: Never really know with :checked selector, maybe try using .prop()? Example above